# Is it a problem to go to sleep just after a big dinner?

Tags: sleep, eating

Our kid is nearly 3 years old and really enjoy eating. We have dinner together when I come back from work at around 20:00, and he eats a lot. His belly is really full then. Recently he wakes up during the night. I wonder if it is a bad thing to go to sleep with the belly full.

Comment: I'd say it's perfectly natural -- we all get sleepy after a big meal.

Answer (score 1):

Adults often go to sleep with a full belly.  I am not sure why that would be waking him up? Certain foods can make sleeping more difficult, but assuming you are having healthy meals I don't see this as a problem.
Three year olds often wake up in the middle of the night.

I would evaluate for night tremors.

1. Is he fully awake when he 'wakes up'?
2. Does he scream when he wakes up or does he wake up like it is morning?
3. What does he do/need when he wakes up?
4. Is he going back to sleep?

Three year olds are just developing the idea of what fear feels like and often that makes them wake up at night.

I wouldn't worry about the food and the full belly, nor really the waking up, I would more deal with the situation until he stops waking up.

Comment: You had a small typo in your formatting; now the numbered list is prettified.

Comment: Thanks Morah. When he wakes up he cries a bit to call us but it doesn't look like he had a nightmare. He is not very awake but nor is he in the morning... He is conscious however. This night he had to go to the pot to do the big thing. He is going back to sleep without problems.

Answer (score 0):

My children all slept fine after late-night feedings, and so I don't think this is any kind of danger or contributor to his waking up at night.

His schedule of bathroom use might become a little unusual, but kids are resilient.